# What are those yellow orbs that enemies drop?

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

Occasionally, I've seen enemies drop yellow orbs, and I can't figure out what they do. They're especially plentiful during the final boss fight, but that's not the only place. Green's health, blue's focus, purple's power, but what could yellow be?

(btw, I don't mean the quest guide. ;) )

Comment: bonus experience?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Possibly, I thought of that, but I couldn't tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual, there are only three types of orbs that enemies drop.  There are definitely green and yellow, I think you may be seeing blue and purple as separate, when they're the same orb (which I will refer to as blue, since that is how my TV renders it).

> **Health, Focus and Orbs** - Ehb is a dangerous place, full of
>   adversaries who hate the Legion. When an enemy injures you, your
>   Health will be reduced.  If you use your Special Abilities to strike
>   back, you will deplete your Focus and Power.  One way to replenish
>   these resources is by collecting orbs.
>
> There are Orbs of Health, Focus and Power. Walk over an Orb to
>   replenish a small amount of the resource associated with that Orb's
>   type.
>
> You can find these Orbs by defeating enemies and smashing destructible
>   items.
>
> -- Dungeon Siege III manual, page 5

So, from this and gameplay:

- Green = Health
- Blue = Focus
- Yellow = Power

Comment: hmm, that sounds very possible. :)